# Tkinter: a simple way to avoid race conditions between an event and value update?

Tags: python, binding, tkinter, race-condition

### The issue

My issue is pretty simple, but I couldn't figure out how to cope with it easily even after some googling.

So I have a checkbutton:

```
self.but_val = IntVar()
self.but = Checkbutton(frame, text="text", variable=self.but_val)
```

This checkbutton triggers updates of some file path on the GUI:

```
self.but.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', 
        lambda e: self.update_files_path(e), add='+')
```

In `update_files_path(event)`, I need to get the value of the checkbutton to select the file paths to be displayed:

```
if self.but_val.get() == 0:
    [...]
else:
    [...]
```

**The issue I have is that I get the value of the button before the clic.**
And since the processing of file paths depends on different button values, I can't just use the opposite value.

### My current work around

At the moment I have a function that is triggered before the clic and that save the state of the GUI:

```
self.but.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda e,
    self.save_design_opts_state(self.buttons_to_backup,
        self.before_clic_vars_state), add='+')
```

Then in `update_files_path(event)` I call a function that infers the GUI state after the clic:

```
gui_state = self.get_gui_state(event)
```

This function is very annoying to implement, because I need to do a lot of things:
 1- Check that the clic is really made on a button (to avoid a clic that starts on a button and end elsewhere!)
 2- Get the value of the of all required buttons depending of their type

**Is there an easier way to deal with this?**

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set your own bindings. Use the `command` option of the checkbutton. This option lets you specify a command to be run after the value has changed. There are other ways, but this is by far the simplest, most common way to solve your problem.

Comment: The tutorial I made didn't show that `command` can be used on different buttons types. I only used it on classic buttons. Everytime I had checkbuttons or radiobuttons I used the `bind` method... With `command`, my code will be much more clear and clean (after lot of rework though...). Thank you for your answer!